# Unable to add new code for Python Selenium Tests

Tags: python, git, selenium

I am writing python selenium tests

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

This is my `main.py` file, I import the tests from a different folder

```
from tests.AuthorTest import AuthorTest
```

When I run main.py it gives me a message

```
python main.py

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
```

for some reason, when I pull the code from git hub I can edit and change existing files but when I add new tests to `main.py`, it still says Ran 0 tests. Im guessing the main isn't importing it correctly? Been having this problem for a while and I can't seem to fix it.

Appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Are your test files corrected stored in the appropriate directory structure in your project?

Comment: Yes, all files are stored in the appropriate directory. When i import it into main i don't get any error messages it just doesn't run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All test functions when using unittest modules should begin with `test` in your test file.

"*A testcase is created by subclassing unittest.TestCase. The three individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the letters test. This naming convention informs the test runner about which methods represent tests.*"
From http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html

```
class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    def choice(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

will not show any result but when `def choice(self)` is renamed to `def testchoice(self)`, unittest now will show that one of the tests failed.

Comment: The shared example works, the problem occurs when I attempt to add more tests to the main

Comment: @user3375657 I had the same problem with unittests before. Did you append `test` to your funciton name? Could you post what content you added newly to the test file?

Comment: So anything that exists when I pull the code from git hub will run and I will be able to edit it. 
examples
from tests.ContributerLoginTest import ContributerLoginTest
from tests.AdminLoginTest import AdminLoginTest

when I attempt to add something
from tests.TestScript import TestScript

It wont run, the main.py doesn't see it (its not commented out) 

the main.py will return " 0 tests run in 0.000s"